# iOS keyboard no longer shows after upgrading environment

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, webview

i hadn't touched the code of my iOS app in a while, and since then the latest iOS version became 4.3.2.  i upgraded my environment in both XCode and on my device.  after compiling my application and running it in both the simulator and on device, the keyboard no longer shows up when selecting editable items inside a webview.

my app's first screen is an OAuth dialog, and as such, I can't get past it without the keyboard, so i tried embedding an edit box in the same parent view as the webview, and it worked!  except, the dismiss keyboard button did not work - the keyboard stayed visible even when i pressed it.  touching away from the edit box (thus forcing it to resign first responder status) did make the keyboard go away.

i figured it would be something in my webview delegate code, but didn't see anything there that could stop a keyboard from showing.

in the XIB that sets up the webview, i checked that user interaction is enabled, so that's not the problem either.  when i touch an edit box in the webview, the edit box enters editing mode - the keyboard just doesn't show.

Comment: That's a weird one. You might want to check this ADC thread - https://devforums.apple.com/message/375950

Comment: @nick weaver - i actually had no idea i needed to do that on stackoverflow.

Comment: same problem like me. did you found a solution ?